# jQuery check p tag value then hide parent if criteria matched

Tags: jquery

I want to lookup prices inside

tags (plain text).
For instance if p.price < 10000 then hide its parent.
Im thinking something along the lines of

```
$(".price").val() < 10000.parent().hide();
```

Obviously that is syntactically incorrect....can anyone tell me if this is possible and how i'd go about cleaning up my code? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) or [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$(".price").each(function(){    
   if($(this).val() < 10000)
      $(this).parent().hide();    
});
```

*OR*

```
$(".price").filter(function(){    
   return $(this).val() < 10000;  
}).hide();
```

**Edit** based on comments

```
$(this).val().replace('£','').replace(/,/g,'')
```

Your code would be

```
$(".price").each(function(){    
   if($(this).val().replace('£','').replace(/,/g,'') < 10000)
      $(this).parent().hide();    
});
```

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" if when trying to use the first suggestion

Comment: ok it now runs but makes no changes - the format of the field is: £19,525 - could this be causing it to not find the correct values?

Comment: It still runs and comes back with results but doesn't make any changes to the page...this is very odd